# Simplify equation - Wolfram providing different answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation $-n = m-x(a-w(x-\frac{2l}{3})) - w(x-\frac{2l}{3})(\frac{l}{3}+\frac{x}{2})$

I have simplified this to

$n = -m + ax - w(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{2l^2}{3})$

However Wolfram and my online module are giving me different answers (about the same length as the original equation) for some reason.

Can anyone have an attempt at simplifying that and let me know where I have gone wrong

Comment: Please check your parentheses in your first line. I tried editing your formatting, but realized that your equation is ambiguous because you have non-matched parens.

Answer (score 0):

Should you have a $wx2l/3$ term?

Comment: Quite possibly. I have spen 6 hours on it but can't find exactly where I have gone wrong